# Can I create an alert if I am combining two function from one onclick event? (Pure Javascript)

Tags: javascript, alert

Newbie here.  I am really struggling with JavaScript and am working on a daily goal calendar for myself just for practice.  I have 5 checkboxes and one button which on clicking adds the total of checked boxes
The first function I have works fine:
With a second function I would like to take the total count from the first and have an alert message.  For some reason (probably something very obvious) I can't get the alert to pop up.
Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```js
let count;

function checkboxes() {
  var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    count = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < inputElems.length; i++) {
    if (inputElems[i].type == "checkbox" && inputElems[i].checked == true) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  console.log(count);
}


function goalDigger() {
  let comp = count;
  if (comp == 5) {
    alert("5 star day!");

  } else if (comp == 4) {
    alert("4 for the win! Hang your hat on that!");

  } else if (comp == 3) {
    alert("Three is ok sometimes..");

  } else if (comp == 2) {
    alert("Well, you got out of bed today so..good job!");

  } else if (comp == 1) {
    alert("What happened??");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="learning">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultUnchecked">30 Minutes of Learning</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="workout">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultUnchecked">Workout</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="facebook">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultUnchecked">NO Facebook App</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="diet">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultUnchecked">Clean Eating</label>
    </div>
   <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="meditate">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultUnchecked">Meditation</label>
    </div> 

<button onclick="checkboxes(); goalDigger()">Tally me Banana!</button>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML

Comment: I feel you should avoid the *old-style* `on{eventName}` way of handling events (both `object.onclick` in JS and `<element onclick=""`` in HTML). You should always prefer `object.addEventListener( 'eventName', handlerFunc )` instead.

Comment: @Noob1223 - did you read my message and could you please add your checkboxes? I tried to guess and guessed wrong the first time so I fixed the values of the checkboxes

Comment: @mplungjan I just added the buttons from my HTML. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Noob1223 Please see [my amended answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64505907/295783). It is a lot simpler than my original answer since I saw your HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is not recommended to use inline event handlers
2. You need the number of checkboxes in the second function, but count is not available to the second function due to scope of your `var ... , count` which declares a new variable with scope local to the function instead of updating the global var defined by `let count` outside the functions.

Here is a simpler version that only has ONE function

```js
// have an array of texts
const texts = ["Nothing checked", "What happened??", "Well, you got out of bed today so..good job!", "Three is ok sometimes..", "4 for the win! Hang your hat on that!", "5 star day!"]

window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when page loads
  document.getElementById("sumBut").addEventListener("click", function() { // clicking the button
    const comp = document.querySelectorAll(".custom-checkbox input:checked").length; // count all checked boxes
    alert(texts[comp]); // alert the matching text
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="learning">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultUnchecked">30 Minutes of Learning</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="workout">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultUnchecked">Workout</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="facebook">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultUnchecked">NO Facebook App</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="diet">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultUnchecked">Clean Eating</label>
    </div>
   <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="meditate">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultUnchecked">Meditation</label>
    </div> 
<button id="sumBut" type="button">Tally me Banana!</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am going to study and try to wrap my reptile brain around it. Thanks for the comments in the code, that will help.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are redclaring count inside the function, it does not change the global variable

```
var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    count = 0; <--- declares count as a new variable
```

change it to

```
var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
count = 0;
```

better yet, have the one function call the other

```
function checkboxes() {
  var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    count = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < inputElems.length; i++) {
    if (inputElems[i].type == "checkbox" && inputElems[i].checked == true) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}


function goalDigger() {
  let comp = checkboxes();
  if (comp == 5) {
    alert("5 star day!");

  } else if (comp == 4) {
    alert("4 for the win! Hang your hat on that!");

  } else if (comp == 3) {
    alert("Three is ok sometimes..");

  } else if (comp == 2) {
    alert("Well, you got out of bed today so..good job!");

  } else if (comp == 1) {
    alert("What happened??");
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked great and your explanation made perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: It is however still much more complex than necessary and is not addressing the usage of inline event handlers which is not receommended

Comment: @mplungjan Agree, but was addressing the major issue in the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no else condition for when count is 0 :)

```js
let count;

function checkboxes() {
  var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    count = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < inputElems.length; i++) {
    if (inputElems[i].type == "checkbox" && inputElems[i].checked == true) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  console.log(count);
}


function goalDigger() {
  let comp = count;
  if (comp == 5) {
    alert("5 star day!");

  } else if (comp == 4) {
    alert("4 for the win! Hang your hat on that!");

  } else if (comp == 3) {
    alert("Three is ok sometimes..");

  } else if (comp == 2) {
    alert("Well, you got out of bed today so..good job!");

  } else if (comp == 1) {
    alert("What happened??");
  } else { alert('you are here'); }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="checkboxes(); goalDigger()">Tally me Banana!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have used button but your js code is for input.
2. On your code button click count starts with 0 and then count is going to change  +1.
3. There is no type like checkbox. It's a "nodeName:BUTTON" I found.

Hope this code will gonna help you.

```js
var count = 0;
function checkboxes() {
  var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
  
//console.log(inputElems);
  for (var i = 0; i < inputElems.length; i++) {
    if (inputElems[i].nodeName == "BUTTON") {
     count++;
    }
  }
 // console.log(count);
}


function goalDigger() {
  let comp = count;
  if (comp == 5) {
    alert("5 star day!");

  } else if (comp == 4) {
    alert("4 for the win! Hang your hat on that!");

  } else if (comp == 3) {
    alert("Three is ok sometimes..");

  } else if (comp == 2) {
    alert("Well, you got out of bed today so..good job!");

  } else if (comp == 1) {
    alert("What happened??");
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="checkboxes(); goalDigger()">Tally me Banana!</button>
```